# Python and pandas: Convert a column in CSV file to integer

Tags: python, pandas, plot

My requirement is to read a csv file with columns: Date, Maximum temperature (TMAX), Min temperature(TMIN)
Later I need to summarize by quarter and plot a bar graph.

I am using the below code but it is not working.

```
#importing necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Reading the file using pandas
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\home\Downloads\2285297.csv", parse_dates = ['DATE'])

# Reading each column
np_maxtemp= df.loc[:,['TMAX']]
np_mintemp= df.loc[:,['TMIN']]
np_date= df.loc[:,['DATE']]

#Summarizing Max temp by each quarter
df['np_quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.DATE, freq='Q')
#It gives me list of all quarters 0 2010Q1   1 2010Q2

avg_tmax=df.groupby(by=['np_quarter'])['TMAX'].mean()
avg_tmin=df.groupby(by=['np_quarter'])['TMIN'].mean()
#It gives me averages by quarter


# Then I want to plot with quarters on x-axis and temperature bar plots on y-axis
plt.plot(df['np_quarter'])
plt.ylabel(avg_prec)
plt.show()
```

First line itself is giving an error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'

How can I convert those quarters to string and plot average temperatures on y-axis?

### Data

```py
   STATION       DATE  PRCP  TMAX  TMIN np_quarter
0   USW00012921 2010-12-01   0.0  65.0  29.0     2010Q4
1   USW00012921 2010-12-02   0.0  71.0  37.0     2010Q4
2   USW00012921 2010-12-03   0.0  76.0  44.0     2010Q4
3   USW00012921 2010-12-04   0.0  79.0  55.0     2010Q4
4   USW00012921 2010-12-05   0.0  60.0  41.0     2010Q4
5   USW00012921 2010-12-06   0.0  59.0  36.0     2010Q4
6   USW00012921 2010-12-07   0.0  60.0  36.0     2010Q4
7   USW00012921 2010-12-08   0.0  60.0  37.0     2010Q4
8   USW00012921 2010-12-09   0.0  65.0  31.0     2010Q4
9   USW00012921 2010-12-10   0.0  74.0  39.0     2010Q4
10  USW00012921 2010-12-11   0.0  75.0  43.0     2010Q4
11  USW00012921 2010-12-12   0.0  60.0  34.0     2010Q4
12  USW00012921 2010-12-13   0.0  60.0  29.0     2010Q4
13  USW00012921 2010-12-14   0.0  72.0  38.0     2010Q4
14  USW00012921 2010-12-15   0.0  76.0  46.0     2010Q4
15  USW00012921 2010-12-16   0.0  64.0  48.0     2010Q4
16  USW00012921 2010-12-17   0.0  57.0  41.0     2010Q4
17  USW00012921 2010-12-18   0.0  58.0  34.0     2010Q4
18  USW00012921 2010-12-19   0.0  67.0  34.0     2010Q4
19  USW00012921 2010-12-20   0.0  76.0  48.0     2010Q4
```

Comment: First line? the import or the read_csv? I cannot replicate your issue with the current information.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an issue with loading the file as it is delimited with whitespace rather than commas. I wasn't certain what you wanted to plot but here is the average for each quarter (min and max). I also put spaces around operators as is suggested in PEP8 to improve readability. Let me know if it doesn't work.

```
#Reading the file using pandas
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\home\Download\2285297.csv", delim_whitespace=True)  # delimiter is whitespace not comma
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

# Reading each column
np_maxtemp = df.loc[:, ['TMAX']]
np_mintemp = df.loc[:, ['TMIN']]
np_date = df.loc[:, ['DATE']]

#Summarizing Max temp by each quarter
df['np_quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.DATE, freq='Q')
#It gives me list of all quarters 0 2010Q1   1 2010Q2

avg_tmax = df.groupby(by=['np_quarter'])['TMAX'].mean()
avg_tmin = df.groupby(by=['np_quarter'])['TMIN'].mean()
#It gives me averages by quarter

# Then I want to plot with quarters on x-axis and temperature bar plots on y-axis
plt.plot([str(avg_tmax.index[0]) + " MAX",
          str(avg_tmax.index[0]) + " MIN"],
         [avg_tmax[0], avg_tmin[0]],
         'o')
plt.ylabel('avg_prec')  # change to str
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I use whitespace delimitter I get below error for line np_maxtemp= df.loc[:,['TMAX']]: "Error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['TMAX'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: did you also add the line ```df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])``` underneath? try to copy and paste the whole code block just to check if it works in full; at the moment I can't reproduce the error with the above code.

Comment: If I use the code exactly, I get error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\home\\Download\\2285297.csv'. or if I modify the read file line as: df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\home\Downloads\2285297.csv", delim_whitespace=True), I get error: File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'DATE'. I am using python version 3.8.5

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that there is some difference in file format, I copied and pasted your example into notepad and saved as .csv. It might be worth trying that with your original CSV as it is working for me (python 3.7), otherwise sorry I can't be of more help.